# I can not get supplemental_display_text from the Google Assistant API if I ask for location etc

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I installed assistant-sdk-python and tried it. I can get audio responses. In some cases, I can also get text response, if I ask for time, weather or small talk etc. But if I ask for location, I can get only the supplemental_display_text "null".
When I change the ScreenMode to "Playing", I can get only HTML response but any text response.
Please let me know if anyone knows the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Not every request with the Assistant SDK is guaranteed to return a string of text. `supplemental_display_text` is supplemental. If you change the ScreenMode, you will get HTML in lieu of text as the text you'd normally get will be embedded in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
I think that Google doesn't give the HTML specification and there are some patterns in HTML response, but is it easy to parse it?

Comment: If you inspect the HTML, it's reasonably easy to pull out the values that you want.